# Build a typing speed test / measuring CPM

Tags: code-golf

### The Rules

It's time to build a typing speed test in your language of choice!

**1**. You provide a file with a dictionary of choice (every 'word' in it must be newline delimited). Pipe it in via `stdin` or provide it's name as a command line argument.

```
a
able
about
above
absence
...
```

**2**. Pick 10 random words from the file (no duplicates must be allowed) and print them out in the following manner:

```
-> direct
-> ground
-> next
-> five
...
```

**3**. Start measuring the time spent from now on!

**4**. Let the user type all of the ten words as fast as possible (ended with a carriage return). Print `OK` when you have a match, print `WRONG` when we have a typing mistake (or the word was already succesfully typed in this run).

**5**. Stop the clocks! Now print the *CPM* (Characters per minute) benchmark, which is calculated as follows: `(sum of the characters of the chosen words / time spent typing (seconds)) * 60`. Round to the nearest integer and reproduce the following (sample) output:

```
--> You have scored 344 CPM!
```

### A sample run

```
-> settle
-> side
-> open
-> minister
-> risk
-> color
-> ship
-> same
-> size
-> sword
settle
OK
side
OK
open
OK
# ...................... some lines snipped ......................
word
WRONG
sword
OK
--> You have scored 298 CPM!
```

### The winner

This is code colf, the shortest entry (in source code character count) wins, have fun!

Comment: I think the winner should partly be scored by the person with the highest CPM ;)

Comment: How precisely do we need to measure the time? Is one second resolution OK?

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: a one second resolution would be fine for this specific contest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## K, 146

Assumes a dictionary file called 'd' in the current working directory.

```
{b:+/#:'a:10?_0:`:d;-1"-> ",/:a;s:.z.t;while[#a;$[(,/0:0)~*a;[a:1_a;-1"OK"];-1"WRONG"]];-1"--> You have scored ",($(60000*b)%"i"$.z.t-s)," CPM!";}
```

Comment: Very nice and short, first entry in `K` I've seen (here on codegolf.se)...

Comment: Thanks, all of my answers here are in Q or (increasingly) in K.

Comment: I don't quite get why this only got a single upvote (mine)!

Answer (score 11):

### Bash - <strike>217</strike> <strike>212</strike> <strike>199</strike> 196 chars

Not gonna win but it was fun

```sh
declare -A W
for w in `shuf -n10`;do C+=$w;echo -\> $w;W[$w]=OK;done
SECONDS=0
for((;${#W[*]};));do read r;echo ${W[$r]-WRONG};unset W[$r];done
echo --\> You have scored $((60*${#C}/SECONDS)) CPM!
```

Under 200 chars now!

<strike>Takes wordlist file as an argument</strike>
Now takes word list on standard input. Paste it in the terminal and press ^D

Implemented suggestion from manatwork

Comment: *Not gonna win but it was fun* - I think the same when I post my C# solutions :)

Comment: You could use the `$SECONDS` shell variable to simplify calculating the elapsed time.

Comment: You can remove 2 more characters: 1) the `:` in the default value parameter expansion; 2) the `$` in front of `SECONDS` in the arithmetic evaluation. Actually there is another extra character, the newline at the and of file.

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby (<del>189</del> <del>178</del> <del>171</del> 168)

```ruby
$><<t=['',d=[*$<.lines].sample(10)]*'-> '
s=Time.now
puts d.delete($stdin.gets)?:OK:'WRONG'while d[0]
puts'--> You have scored %i CPM!'%((t.size-40)/(Time.now-s)*60)
```

Pretty basic, I'm sure there are improvements to be made.  Takes the filename of the dictionary as a command-line argument.

**EDIT**: A few minor tweaks, mainly around retaining the newlines from the dictionary.  As a result the file will need a trailing newline to work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

### C, 305 <strike>309</strike> <strike>347</strike> chars

```
char*stdin,w[11][99];long i,t;main(int n,char**v){v=fopen(v[1],"r");
for(srand(time(&t));fgets(w[i++>9?(n=rand()%i)>10?0:n:i],99,v););
for(i=n=0;i<10;n+=printf("-> %s",w[++i])-4);
for(;i;puts(!strcmp(*w,w[11-i])?--i,"OK":"WRONG"))fgets(*w,99,stdin);
printf("--> You have scored %ld CPM!\n",n*60/(time(0)-t));}
```

Thanks to @ugoren for the improvement hints. Using an "11th word" to discard incoming dictionary entries was a big win over my previous strcpy-if-chosen approach.

Here's the ungolfed source:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

static char words[11][99];
static long i, t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int n;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    srand(time(0));
    for (i = 0 ; fgets(words[0], sizeof words[0], fp) ; ++i) {
        n = i < 10 ? i : rand() % i;
        if (n < 10)
            strcpy(words[n + 1], words[0]);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    n = 0;
    for (i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; ++i)
        n += printf("-> %s", words[i]) - 4;
    t = time(0);
    i = 1;
    while (i <= 10 && fgets(words[0], sizeof words[0], stdin)) {
        if (strcmp(words[0], words[i])) {
            puts("WRONG");
        } else {
            puts("OK");
            ++i;
        }
    }
    if (i > 9)
        printf("-> You have scored %ld CPM!\n", n * 60 / (time(0) - t));

    return argc - argc;
}
```

Comment: Some improvements: 1. K&R declaration: `main(n,v)char**v;{...`. 2. `stdin` can be `char *`. `fgets(buf,len,stdin)`=`gets(buf)` (never mind the buffer overruns). 3. What's wrong with `rand()%i`? `RAND_MAX` isn't needed. 4. Why `long`?

Comment: Also: 1) `t=time(0)`->`time(&t)`. 2) `n*60/(time(0)-t)` has parentheses that must go - `*60` can be moved to `n+=60*printf`, then `n/=time(0)-t`. 3) Replace `b` with an extra element in `w`, replace `strcpy` with read directly into `w`.

Comment: Replacing `fgets()` with `gets()` needs extra code to deal with the newlines in the dictionary; this wound up being shorter. `rand()%i` isn't sufficient; the actual calculation is `(double)i*rand()/RAND_MAX`. Moving the `*60` to the printf also means changing the the `-4` to `-240` so it ultimately winds up a loss. Your other points are valid ones, though (I believe). Oh, and `long` is because time_t is traditionally a long. Just because we're golfing doesn't mean we can't be portable.

Comment: I missed `4`->`240`... Portability and golf don't go well together. But defining `i,t;` (implicitly int) is OK up to `MAX_INT` seconds (if you don't use `time(&t)`). With `rand()`, all you need is a `10/i` chance, and `rand()%i<10` does it.

Comment: Your random selection is somewhat flawed (not that absolute fairness is required). The 11th line should have a 10/11 chance to be selected, but you do `rand()%10>10`, which gives it 100%. `rand()%(i+1)>9` is better (but instead if `%(i+1)` do `i++>9?`. Also move `*stdin` to be first and save a space.

Comment: It's already flawed by using rand()%i instead of floating-point -- but you're right, there's a serious bug there. It does need to be `>10` though. It's not obvious, but the code is (meant to be) taking advantage of the fact that w[0] is the trashbucket entry, so `rand()%11>10` still has a 10/11 chance to be selected. The bug is due to me making logic changes to already-golfed code; fortunately, the fix will actually make it smaller.

Comment: You're right about `>10`. The tricky part is that you can fall in bucket 0 if `rand()%i` is either >10 or 0. About distribution - any random function which returns a finite representation cant give perfect 11-way distribution. Floating point isn't better than fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## Scala(<strike>319</strike> <strike>306</strike> <s>304</s> 302)

```
var s=util.Random.shuffle(io.Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines.toSet)take 10
def?(a:Any)=println(a)
var l=(0/:s){_+_.size}
s map{"-> "+_}map?
def n=System.nanoTime
val t=n
while(s.size!=0){val m=readLine
if(s contains m)?("OK")else?("WRONG");s-=m}
?("--> You have scored "+l*60000000000L/(n-t)+" CPM!")
```

Answer (score 2):

### C# 401

```
void T(){
Action<string>C=Console.WriteLine;Func<string>R=Console.ReadLine;
var w=new List<string>();
for(var l=R();l!="";l=R())w.Add(l);
var s=w.OrderBy(_=>Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10).ToList();
s.ForEach(x=>C("=> "+x));
var t=s.Select(x=>x.Length).Sum();
var c=Stopwatch.StartNew();
while(s.Any()){C(s.Remove(R())?"OK":"WRONG");}
c.Stop();
C("--> You have scored "+c.Elapsed.TotalSeconds*60/t+" CPM!");}
```

Running version here: http://ideone.com/Nt6Id

Answer (score 2):

### PHP 187 bytes

Newlines have been added for clarity:

```
<?$s=file($argv[1]);
for(shuffle($s);$i++<10;$l+=strlen($$i))echo~ÒÁß,$$i=$s[$i];
for($t=time();$j++<10;)echo$$j==fgets(STDIN)?OK:WRONG,~õ?>
--> You have scored <?=0|$l/(time()-$t)*60?> CPM!
```

Accepts the dictionary filename as a command line argument. The dictionary file must end with a newline.

Answer (score 2):

### Python (<s>256</s> 235)

```python
import time as t,random as r
def p(x):print x
c=r.sample(input().split("\n"),10)
z=lambda x:p(("WRONG","OK")[raw_input()==x])or len(x)
p("--> "+"\n--> ".join(c))
_=t.time()
p("--> You have scored %d CPM!"%(sum(map(z,c))/(t.time()-_)*60))
```

This is in python 2.x, in 3.x I can shave off 4 more characters by using the print function.

Newlines included

Comment: "Question: Do newlines count?"  We usually go by "necessary characters".  In the case of Python, yes, the newlines need to be counted, since removing them will keep the program from working.

Comment: I think you can change `z=lambda x:` to `def z(x):`.

Comment: @JoeyAdams: I could if only needed to return none, but I need to return `len(x)` and `def z(x):return` is 5 more charaters :/

Comment: I think you can win some characters by piping in the input (allowed in the question) and using `input()` instead of `sys.argv[1].read()`

Comment: @JoelCornett: Whoops, you're right.

Comment: @ChristopheD: Good idea!

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)], 212 bytes

```
n=10;Print["-> "<>#]&/@(w=RandomWord@n);c=1;t=First@AbsoluteTiming[While[c<=n,Print@If[Echo@InputString[]==w[[c]],c++;"OK","WRONG"]]];Print["--> You have scored "<>ToString@⌊60Total@StringLength@w/t⌋<>" CPM!"]
```

Interesting challenge for WM.
Works only on desktop!
Using internal dictionary of common words instead of file.
Ungolfed version:

```
num = 10; Print["-> " <> #] & /@ (words = RandomWord@num);
size = Total@StringLength@words;
count = 1;
timing = First@AbsoluteTiming[
    While[count <= num,
     Print[
      If[Echo@InputString[] == words[[count]],
       count++; "OK",
       "WRONG"]
      ]
     ]];
result = ToString@⌊60 size/timing⌋;
Print["--> You have scored " <> result <> " CPM!"]
```